# Is there any condition for a square matrix that guarantees it has at least 1 positive *and* at least 1 negative eigenvalue?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

Wondering if there exists any known condition for a square matrix that guarantees it has at least 1 positive *and* at least 1 negative eigenvalue?

Comment: In a two-dimensional space, its determinant has to be negative. In other cases, I'm not sure it's possible to say anything in general.

Comment: real symmetric traceless with a negative determinant?

Comment: E.g. (1) $A$ is Hermitian, nonsingular and traceless, (2) $A$ is either Hermitian or entrywise positive, and it has a positive trace but a negative determinant, or (3) $A$ is a Hermitian matrix with some positive and some negative leading principal minors and the signs of its leading principal minors are not alternating.

Comment: @achillehui real symmetric, traceless , and not the zero matrix should be enough

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone! Actually most interested in the non-traceless case e.g. (2) by @user1551 for e.g. a graph Laplacian. Do you have any references for a proof of this?